# Adding more elements than allocated space

Tags: c++, arrays

In my data structure class, teacher gave us a simple code to print elements from an array with a loop. I declared an array with 10 elements but initialized 15 elements with value 5 than printing 15 elements knowing that rest of elements will show garbage value. But it outputs only 5 elements. As a matter of fact it shows the number of elements I initialize the array to. I am using codeblocks 13.12.
thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i,n;
    int arr[10];
    n=15;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i] = 5;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Writing (or reading for that matte) out of bounds of *anything* leads to *undefined behavior*. Don't do it.

Comment: If you do stupid things you are on your own.

Comment: Oh, and if you don't know the size of the array at time of compilation, then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which allows you to set the size at run-time, and of course append new elements at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the code is undefined. There is very little to be gained by reasoning about what it might do. Just fix the array size. (chances are that one of the out-of-bounds writes is overwriting the value of `n`).

Answer (score 2):

The program has undefined behaviour because the memory outside the array was overwritten.

And it is the reason why in your system the program outputed only 5 elements. Variable `n` was overwritten with value 5 in the following loop when the array was initialized.

```
//...
int arr[10];
n=15;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    arr[i] = 5;
}
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of code produces undefined behavior--that is, code whose behavior is not defined by the standard, so compilers can do anything they want about it. Don't do this. Other examples of undefined behavior include

- Divide by zero
- Reading/writing a `NULL` pointer
- Overflowing signed integers
- Double free
- etc...

Answer (score 1):

C++ compiler do not bound check for array size. Sometimes it will give desired output, other time it will crash. This will lead to *Undefined behavior*.

You should definitely avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

This is badly coded with very little effort or research. This is your homework, at least spend time on it doing it corretly.

Here is some little help but not all:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i,n;
    int arr[10];
    n=15;
    int x;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    arr[i] = x
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }

return 0;    
}
```

There is a few thing you got to do to make it work. I will not do it!